# Change select box option text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-selectbox

I'm working on an ajax select box that loads file content into the closest div area 
**[Demo](http://painfulmouth.com/test/index3.php#)**.
I'm using the script below to change the first option text "Select" to "Hide" when the ajax content is loaded.However, I can't get the **"Hide"** text to change back to **"Select"** after on clicking it.

Code:

```
var area = $(".selectboxarea");
$(".searchselectbox").on('change', function (e) {
    area.empty();
    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
    var loadfile = selected.data('file');

    if (loadfile) {    
        $(this).next('.selectboxarea').load(loadfile);
        $(this).find('option:contains("Select")').text("Hide");
    } else {
        window.location.href = $(this).val();
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<select class="searchselectbox">
    <option value="#">Select</option>
    <option data-file="fans.php">Fans</option>
    <option data-file="stars.php">Stars</option>

</select>
<div class="selectboxarea"></div>
```

Should I use this line in a function?

```
$(this).find('option:contains("Hide")').text("Select");
```

Comment: If I add the last line, in your Question, and create a fiddle this works [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/szHZv/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a class to the `<option>` that needs its text to be changed, like:

```
<option value="#" class="select">Select</option>
```

And then the Js would be

```
var $this = $(this);
var selected = $this.find('option:selected');
var loadfile = selected.data('file');

if (loadfile) {    
    $this.next('.selectboxarea').load(loadfile);
    $this.find('.select').text('Hide');
    $this.find('.select').toggleClass('hide');
} else if (selected.hasClass('hide')) {
    selected.text('Select');
    selected.toggleClass('hide');
} else {
    window.location.href = $(this).val();
}
```

When there's a file data attribute, the text changes and class "hide" is added on the first `option`. After that, if the selected option has the class "hide", the text is changed and the class is removed.

Also, I'm using `var $this = $(this);` to cache the jQuery variable, since it's a good practice to not hace the script look for them every time they are needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do multiple selection which hides the one already selected data. Well, in order to give your users a good view experience(your example is quite dull for multiple selection - the demo), make use of this jquery library: [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). I have always use this for multiple selection whether loading it with ajax (examples included). Take a look.